# Enabled GeoServer Layer has Yellow Triangle with Exclamation Mark Warning

Tags: geoserver

I am having an issue with one of my layers in GeoServer (version 2.1.3). The layer does not appear on the Layer Previews page or in GetCapabilities for either WMS or WFS; however, it *does* appear using OpenLayers on my website.

When I look at my Layers and Cached Layers pages, the layer has a yellow exclamation mark in the "Enabled?" field. What does this warning mean? Why would a layer not appear in layer preview or GetCapabilities, but appear on the website?

Edit: It is a large vector layer with points pulled from a directory of shapefiles. I do not see any error messages in the log related to this layer. There is the following error for a different layer, not sure if it's related: 
2019-11-08 12:57:49,078 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - org.geoserver.wfs.WFSException: Feature type MHC:pa_areas unknown

The "Enabled" and "Advertised" boxes are checked on the Edit Layer page. Updating to a current version of GeoServer is not an option at the moment.

I am new to using GeoServer.

Comment: it means there is a problem with that layer. We need to know what type of layer it is and what the error message in the log file is before we can give you more help

Comment: How large a shapefile?

Comment: @IanTurton the SHP File is 5,612 KB. The four files (SHP, SHX, DBF, and PRJ) together are 720,087 KB.

Comment: with out seeing the shapefile it's hard to be of any more help. Does it open ok in QGIS?